# Mysterious OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION, Operation not valid for this user type: []

Tags: error-messages, user-record, error, user, user-admin

I had following situation.
When I tried to edit and save some of custom object CustomObject1__c instance, I received error in the top of the page

```
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Operation not valid for this user type
```

When I investigated deeper, so I have found out that this object CustomObject1_*c has lookup relation to another object CustomObject2*_c for which instance of one more custom object CustomObject3_*c have been trying to be inserted.
Object CustomObject3*_c also has lookup relation to object CustomObject2_*c, so during insert object CustomObject2*_c was considered to be updated with new child relationship record.

So when I tried manually to update corresponding instance of CustomObject2__c object, I saw another error instead of page

```
Can't Perform this Operation
You can't perform this operation with the selected user type. 

Click here to return to the previous page.
```

I was trying to perform this operation under system administrator, so I supposed I had all the permissions to perform any of operations on any object.

Why did I have that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I want to share the answer I have found.

CustomObject2__c has a trigger which tried to modify OwnerId of instance of that object to AssignedUser field value.

I have found out that AssignedUser value for the failing object was inactive user, and it seems inactive user can't own custom object records.

Comment: Correct; new records cannot be assigned to inactive users.

Comment: How about after turning on 'Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions' option under Quick Find -> User Interface?

Comment: Is this some new user permission? On the time of this post there were no such user permissions

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to set the OwnerId of an object to an Inactive User or a User with a Chatter Free license.  There are a few exceptions for Chatter Free license but such as Files, etc but Custom Objects are not allowed.